# Local stored pictures as hyperlink and replication

Tags: sql-server-2005

Dear All, I have a problem. I havea db on the SQL 2005  and will have it replicated to 2-3 other servers but if I have stored hyperlinks that are linked to the pictures on that main server how can I make also the replication with the same setup.

Is there any way that when I move folder with the pictures to the replicated machine somehow edit automatically the links? It does not make sense but I have to ask? Or is there any other scenarios that I can use?

Comment: stored hyperlinks?  Do you mean that the URL is stored in a varchar field?

Comment: Well I do not have them yet stored but I am thinking about it....

Comment: The main reason is that I do not want to repeat steps ones I do them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using SQL Server 2008 then you could leverage the new FileStream feature that allows you to store  binary large object (BLOB) data as files on the file system without breaking the bond with the row. Moreover, FileStream is also supported by backup and replication processes. Here is an article about [FileStream](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) feature.

With SQL Server 2005, you have to do it manually.

Comment: Thanks Orka, I am using SQL 2005 so that means I have to find another way because I have around 3 000 pictures.....

Comment: In that case, i would recommend you to store hyperlink/url of your pictures as a relative path that is start with a parameterized prefix (server/domain name + rootpath etc). This way you can use any file sync software to replicate files between servers and every server can have its own prefix to append to the hyperlinks. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: ok let me test this one, thanks a lot.... if you know any software that I can use please let me know